# Python dictionary, value-key mapping

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary that looks like this `{3:[2,3,4,5],4:[3,6,7,8]}`.
I need to map the values in dictionary to the keys. i.e `{2:[3],3:[3,4],4:[3],5:[3],6:[4],7:[4],8:[4]}`.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the dict and through each value list to build the new structure. You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) (or a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) to save yourself some boilerplate code:

```
data = {3: [2, 3, 4, 5], 4: [3, 6, 7, 8]}
rev = {}

for k, lst in data.items():
    for val in lst:
        rev.setdefault(val, []).append(k)
rev
# {2: [3], 3: [3, 4], 4: [3], 5: [3], 6: [4], 7: [4], 8: [4]}
```

or

```
from collections import defaultdict

rev = defaultdict(list)
for k, lst in data.items():
    for val in lst:
        rev[val].append(k)
```

Comment: just remember to type cast the resultant `rev` to a `dict()` at the end for the `collections` solution

Comment: What for? A `defaultdict` **is** a `dict` already! It can be fully used as such. You are not coding for the output of your debug `prints`, are you?

Comment: I don't know what s/he is coding for. I just wanted to avoid concerns of " *`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [3], 3: [3, 4], 4: [3], 5: [3], 6: [4], 7: [4], 8: [4]})` is different than my desired output. "*

Comment: I know beginners often have that issue. The earlier they realize that the data structure matters, not its `repr(...)` output, the better ;-)